# How to reduce compile time with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I'm in the process of changing part of my C++ app from using an older C type array to a templated C++ container class.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472944/good-c-array-class-for-dealing-with-large-arrays-of-data-in-a-fast-and-memory-e) for details.  While the solution is working very well, each minor change I make to the templated code causes a very large amount of recompilation to take place, and hence drastically slows build time.  Is there any way of getting template code out of the header and back into a cpp file, so that minor implementation changes don't cause major rebuilds?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the general rules apply. Try to reduce coupling between parts of the code. Break up too large template headers into smaller groups of functions used together, so the whole thing won't have to be included in each and every source file.

Also, try to get the headers into a stable state fast, perhaps testing them out against a smaller test program, so they wouldn't need changing (too much) when integrated into a larger program.

(As with any optimization, it might be less worth to optimize for the compiler's speed when dealing with templates, rather than finding an "algorithmic" optimization that reduces the work-load drastically in the first place.)

Comment: +100 You don't test a template inside a huge unrelated project. The template should be as error free as possible before it goes into an unrelated project.

Comment: Oups, didn't see you answer before I posted mine though I guess I was a bit more explicit... en route toward the 10k mark ;) ?

Comment: +1, and pretty much the conclusion I was coming to myself.  Just being a bit lazy about breaking the code out into a smaller test program ;)

Answer (score 34):

Several approaches:

- The [export keyword](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl-export-keyword.html) could theoretically help, but it was poorly supported and was officially removed in C++11.
- Explicit template instantiation (see [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)) is the most straightforward approach, if you can predict ahead of time which instantiations you'll need (and if you don't mind maintaining this list).
- Extern templates, which are already supported by several compilers as extensions.  It's my understanding that extern templates don't necessarily let you move the template definitions out of the header file, but they do make compiling and linking faster (by reducing the number of times that template code must be instantiated and linked).
- Depending on your template design, you may be able to move most of its complexity into a .cpp file.  The standard example is a type-safe vector template class that merely wraps a type-unsafe vector of `void*`; all of the complexity goes in the `void*` vector that resides in a .cpp file.  Scott Meyers gives a more detailed example in *Effective C++* (item 42, "Use private inheritance judiciously", in the 2nd edition).

Comment: "Use private inheritance judiciously" is 39 in my copy (3rd edition), but thanks for the pointer.  I really should re-read Myers two effective books again.

Comment: Effective C++ 3rd edition is very unlike a new edition.  It is essentially a new book that includes the few most relevant items from editions 1 an 2.

Answer (score 10):

Using templates as a problem solving technique can create compilation slowdowns. A classical example of this is the std::sort vs. qsort function from C. The C++ version of this function takes longer to compile because it needs to be parsed in every translation unit and because almost every use of this function creates a different instance of this template (assuming that closure types are usually provided as sorting predicate).

Although these slowdowns are to be expected, there are some rules that can help you to write efficient templates. Four of them are described below.

### The Rule of Chiel

The Rule of Chiel, presented below, describes which C++ constructs are the most difficult ones for the compiler. If possible, it’s best to avoid those constructs to reduce compilation times.

The following C++ features/constructs are sorted in descending order by compile time:

- SFINAE
- Instantiating a function template
- Instantiating a type
- Calling an alias
- Adding a parameter to a type
- Adding a parameter to an alias call
- Looking up a memorized type

Optimizations based on the above rules were used when Boost.TMP was designed and developed. As much as possible, avoid top constructs for quick template compilation.

Below are some examples illustrating how to make use of the rules listed above.

### Reduce Template Instantiations

Let's have a look at std::conditional. Its declaration is:

```
template< bool B, typename T, typename F >
struct conditional;
```

Whenever we change any of three arguments given to that template, the compiler will have to create a new instance of it. For example, imagine the following types:

```
struct first{};
struct second{};
```

Now, all the following will end up in instantiations of different types:

```
using type1 = conditional<true, first, second>;
using type2 = conditional<true, second, first>;
std::is_same_v<type1, type2>; // it’s false

using type3 = conditional<false, first, second>;
using type4 = conditional<false, second, first>;
std::is_same_v<type1, type2>; // it’s false
```

We can reduce the number of instantiations by changing the implementation of conditional to:

```
template <bool>
struct conditional{
     template <typename T, typename F>
     using type = T;
};

template <>
struct conditional<false>{
     template <typename T, typename F>
     using type = F;
};
```

In this case, the compiler will create only two instantiations of type “conditional” for all possible arguments. For more details about this example, check out [Odin Holmes' talk about the Kvasir library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpVPexZHYrQ).

### Create Explicit Template Instantiations

Whenever you suspect that an instance of a template is going to be used often, it’s a good idea to explicitly instantiate it. Usually, `std::string` is an explicit instantiation of `std::basic_string<char>`.

### Create Specializations for Compile-time Algorithms

Kvasir-MPL specializes algorithms for long lists of types to speed them up. You can see [an example of this here](https://github.com/kvasir-io/mpl/blob/development/src/kvasir/mpl/algorithm/sort.hpp). In this header file, the sorting algorithm is manually specialized for a list of 255 types. Manual specialization speeds up compilations for long lists.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, for completeness, I'll cover the straightforward solution: only use templated code when necessary, and base it on non-template code (with implementation in its own source file).

However, I suspect that the real issue is that you use generic programming as you would use typical OO-programming and end up with a bloated class.

Let's take an example:

```
// "bigArray/bigArray.hpp"

template <class T, class Allocator>
class BigArray
{
public:
  size_t size() const;

  T& operator[](size_t index);
  T const& operator[](size_t index) const;

  T& at(size_t index);
  T const& at(size_t index);

private:
  // impl
};
```

Does this shock you ? Probably not. It seems pretty minimalist after all. The thing is, it's not. The `at` methods can be factored out without any loss of generality:

```
// "bigArray/at.hpp"

template <class Container>
typename Container::reference_type at(Container& container,
                                      typename Container::size_type index)
{
  if (index >= container.size()) throw std::out_of_range();
  return container[index];
}

template <class Container>
typename Container::const_reference_type at(Container const& container,
                                            typename Container::size_type index)
{
  if (index >= container.size()) throw std::out_of_range();
  return container[index];
}
```

Okay, this changes the invocation slightly:

```
// From
myArray.at(i).method();

// To
at(myArray,i).method();
```

However, thanks to Koenig's lookup, you can call them unqualified as long as you put them in the same namespace, so it's just a matter of habit.

The example is contrived but the general point stands. Note that because of its genericity `at.hpp` never had to include `bigArray.hpp` and will still produce as tight code as if it were a member method, it's just that we can invoke it on other containers if we wish.

And now, a user of `BigArray` does not need to include `at.hpp` if she does not uses it... thus reducing her dependencies and not being impacted if you change the code in that file: for example alter `std::out_of_range` call to feature the file name and line number, the address of the container, its size and the index we tried to access.

The other (not so obvious) advantage, is that if ever integrity constraint of `BigArray` is violated, then `at` is obviously out of cause since it cannot mess with the internals of the class, thus reducing the number of suspects.

This is recommended by many authors, such as Herb Sutters in [C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586):

> Item 44: Prefer writing nonmember nonfriend functions

and has been extensively used in *Boost*... But you do have to change your coding habits!

Then of course you need to only include what you do depend on, there ought to be static C++ code analyzers that report included but unused header files which can help figuring this out.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and your're quite right about the template code being bloated.  I initially based it on the MFC CArray, which I have since discovered is morbidly obese!  Which static code analyser lists unused headers? I currently use PC-LINT and haven't seen that feature.

Comment: I thought it would be a common thing, but I am afraid I confused it with another language :/ It's strange since (for example) even the C++ colorizer from Eclipse checks for overloads (and only colorize if a correct overload is found)... sorry for misleading you.

Comment: I know this trick and it is also recommended by Scott Meyers. However I think it negatively affect readability of your code. Also visualisers like in Visual Studio don't pick up global functions, and those may speed up your development as well. Boost graph is almost completely designed this way (i.e. free functions operating on abstract graph concepts) and while it is very flexible and powerful it is very hard for beginners to get around in it.

Comment: @gast128: I guess it really depends which language you come from. If you come from; OO is the only paradigm where a function is attached to an object, so it's only hard to grasp for people having had prior exposure to OO and no (or little) exposure to other paradigms (procedural, functional, ...)

Answer (score 6):

- You can use [explicit instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used); however, only the template types you instantiate will compile ahead of time.
- You might be able to take advantage of c++20's [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules).
- If you can factor out the templated types from your algorithm, you can put it in its own .cc file.
- I wouldn't suggest this unless it's a major problem but: you may be able to provide a template container interface that is implemented with calls to a `void*` implementation that you are free to change at will.
- Before c++11 you could use a compiler that supports the [export](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) keyword.

Comment: `export` will be dropped in C++0x. You shouldn't even think about using it now.

Comment: +1 for the explicit instantiation, I hadn't come across this before and think it could help alot.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a base class without templates and move most of the implementation there. The templated array would then define only proxy methods, that use base class for everything.